# Assigning function to function pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers

I have currently defined a function pointer and to me it seems like the function matches the definition, however I am getting an error:

> 1   IntelliSense: a value of type "std::string (RSSCrawler::*)(const web::json::value &headlines)" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "std::string (*)(const web::json::value &headlines)"

I am not sure what is wrong, but here is my code

```
string(*GetHeadline)(const value&headlines);
GetHeadline = Extract;


string RSSCrawler::Extract(const value &headlines)
{
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Plain function pointers are not member function pointers. Research the latter.

Comment: Extract is a member function.  GetHeadline is a non-member function pointer.  They are not the same type.

Comment: it should work if Exrtact is a static function. And you can assign function pointer using GetHeadLine = RSSCrawler::Extract;

Comment: @CODError but the compiler message shows clearly that it's not a `static` member function, and that's the problem. Coincidentally, I edited a note about `static` member functions into my answer just 1 minute before you commented. :P Anyway, making it a `static` method has the same issues as capturing the pointer-to-member in a lambda, in that it complicates things by meaning we must then also provide an instance to work with. As said in my answer to the OP's next question (in Linked) - it's much easier to have the lambda capture `this` and use it to act 'on behalf of' an instance.

Comment: @underscore_d I did see that compiler msg clearly says its not a static method. Thats why i suggested to make it a static method. Then it would be easy to use the pointer in lambdas (i haven't worked much with lambdas as I use mac and it gives problem with c++11; but i have the concept how it works). If you use static method, you can simply pass the reference of the object you want to work with.

Comment: @CODError Of course, and that's what we do when we _need_ to use `static` methods - but objectively, having to provide an instance pointer in addition to a pointer-to-method is an additional complication, which in the case of lambdas is totally unnecessary as capturing `this` covers both.

Comment: @underscore_d Yes, I agree static methods add some complications when you want current object (this) inside your function. But its perfectly fine to use static methods when it doesn't want your current object (this), right? I guess in the example code it doesn't use current object inside method body :P . Static method wins in this case ;) yes? <its just for my own understanding that I am arguing with you>

Comment: @CODError Very true! I was assuming the OP was showing a simplified example and/or that the method is `virtual` and has related overrides that _would_ use instance data. So, I just proceeded from that assumption, without asking whether it actually needs to be an instance method. But maybe it's even simpler than all that, as you said!

Comment: :| maybe I should get an upvote too ;) and thanks @underscore_d!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler explained this with a type mismatch error and showing the difference in the first set of parentheses. You need a *member function pointer*. That is a separate type from a 'plain'/free function pointer. (`static` member functions act like free functions in this sense, but that's not what you have.)

You can find plenty tutorials about these, but here's a quick reference. (I have to restrain myself not to de-capitalise these function and variable names because it just looks wrong, even without SO's auto-formatting.)

```
// Declare pointer-to-member-function of a given class and signature
std::string (RssCrawler::* GetHeadline)(const value&);
// Bind it to any method of the same class and signature
GetHeadline = &RssCrawler::Extract;
// Call it on a given instance of said class
std::cout << (someInstance.*GetHeadline)(someValue) << std::endl; // operator .*
```

Or you can do this to get a `const` initialised pointer, though I think that defeats the purpose of a function pointer, except for `const`-correctness when declaring them as arguments to *other* functions...

```
std::string (RssCrawler::*const GetHeadline)(const value&) {
    &RssCrawler::Extract
}
```