# Passing function pointer into lambda capture list

Tags: c++, lambda, function-pointers

I was wondering if it's possible to pass a member function pointer into a lambda capture list?  I have tried just passing it but to no avail it did not work:

```
GetHeadline = RSSCrawler::Extract;

auto headlines = client.request(methods::GET).then([RSSCrawler::*GetHeadline](http_response response)
{
    if (response.status_code() == status_codes::OK)
    {
        auto jsonContent = response.extract_json().get();
        auto outcome = GetHeadline(jsonContent);
        wcout << jsonContent << endl;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is implicit in my answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38410037): That's not the right syntax for binding a *variable* to a member function. You're telling it to capture the *type* of the pointer, which makes no sense.

Capture the previously defined pointer-to-member-function **variable** by value:

```
[GetHeadline]
```

Or - better - you don't need to declare the pointer outwith the capture list, since we can declare new variables in a capture using type deduction:

```
[GetHeadline = &RssCrawler::Extract]
```

Either way, you need to remember a key point from my other answer: You must **provide an instance on which to call** the pointed method, so change this:

```
auto outcome = GetHeadline(jsonContent);
```

...to this:

```
auto outcome = (some_instance.*GetHeadline)(jsonContent);
```

which, of course, means that you'll have to either capture or pass-in that **instance**, too. Isn't this all getting bit complicated with all these method and instance pointers flying around? Well, thankfully, there's a much better way if you're in the right situation! Which is...

**However**, if you're defining the lambda within a non-`static` member function, you can simply tell it to capture the instance on which said member function is called, by **capturing `this`**. Doing so allows the lambda to call/access anything within the class, as if it *is* that instance:

```
auto headlines = client.request(methods::GET).then(
    [this](http_response response) // capture this instance
    {
        if (response.status_code() == status_codes::OK)
        {
            auto jsonContent = response.extract_json().get();
            auto outcome = Extract(jsonContent); // this->Extract
            wcout << jsonContent << endl;
        }
    }
);
```

So, each time this member function runs, the instance on which it was called is captured within a new lambda, which can act 'on behalf of' that instance.

Comment: I have just tried the latter however I get RSSCrawler::GetHeadline is not a variable.  Also I tried to accept your answer before however I had to wait a minute before I could do it.  Sorry.

Comment: Thanks! See my edit: You need to invoke the pointer-to-member-function on an instance, which you weren't doing. I've also included info on how you can make this much simpler if your lambda is defined within a member function by capturing `this` instead.

Comment: That is a brilliant answer! Thanks!